# How to get Slick Component Instance using view Child

Tags: angular, slick.js

I am new to angular and  trying to implements a paginated carousel [using ngx-slick plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick).

Using this plugin, when the caurosal loads in the template i need to make sure that the caurosal starts from index 1 (not 0). for which this plugin has given a function known as slickGoTo. For calling this function i need the instance of slick component. but whenever i tried to fetch instance of slick component i m getting this 'Error: Cannot read property 'slick' of undefined' error. I have implemented this scenario in [stackblitz url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzf2vx) (jquery is not loading when u open the stackblitz  not sure why ). Please suggest how to fetch the instance of this component

below is template example of using it :

```
<ngx-slick class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-modal" [config]="slideConfig" (afterChange)="afterChange($event)">
        <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
              <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
        </div>
    </ngx-slick>

    <button (click)="addSlide()">Add</button>
    <button (click)="removeSlide()">Remove</button>
    <button (click)="slickModal.slickGoTo(2)">slickGoto 2</button>
    <button (click)="slickModal.unslick()">unslick</button>
```

in which you can see the slickGoto button is present. I need same functionality in my component class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

In your html file.

```
<your-slick-component #slickComponent></your-slick-component>
```

In your ts file.

```
@ViewChild('slickComponent')
public slickComponent: any;

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if(this.slickComponent) {
      this.slickComponent.slickGoTo(1);
    }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: updated the question with example. I m getting the slick component in directive but whenever i fetched it in my component. i m getting undefined. did the same thing as mentioned above not getting the instance of slick

Comment: Did you try to add another variable to the template and passing it to the ts file? #slickModal="slick-modal" and #slick
And refrence the slick component using #slick variable

Comment: i think its not initalizing as intializing this component will take sometime before we are making its instance function call. I m not sure how to use its init event in the component

Comment: Okay. As the final thing try to pass the slick reference to the function.

 `<button (click)="goTo(slickModal)">slickGoto 2</button>`

And in your ts file

`public goTo(slickModal: any): void {
   slickModal.slickGoTo(2)
}`

Comment: yeah got the issue i didnt using slides array name due to which its instance is coming as undefinded after changing item list to slides its working

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with ViewChildren i.e multple slick carousels ?